# Programmatically attaching event handlers

Tags: objective-c, iphone

So, I'm trying to programmatically attach event handlers to widgets I've placed on my iphone application using:

```
addTarget:action:forControlEvents
```

I have added a UISegmentedControl in Interface Builder which is exposed through `@property seg` and in loadView, I have:

```
- (void)loadView
{
  [ super loadView ] ;

  //k after that attach our own event handlers
  [ seg addTarget:seg action:@selector(sliderEventIB) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents ];
}
```

sliderEventIB, just tells us it feels the event:

```
-(IBAction)sliderEventIB:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
  puts( "I feel you joanna" ) ;
}
```

but the error I'm getting is

```
ViewControllersTest[6744:207] *** -[UISegmentedControl sliderEventIB]:
unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3b21b30
```

Any idea what it **doesn't** like here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you just forgot to insert the colon in addTarget:

`[ seg addTarget:seg action:@selector(sliderEventIB:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents ];`

It should be sliderEventIB: not sliderEventIB.

Answer (score 1):

The proper code is as such:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    [super loadView];
    [seg addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderEventIB:forEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllEvents];
}
- (IBAction)sliderEventIB:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    NSLog(@"I feel you joanna");
}
```

Notice that the method has the same selector as is registered using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the UISegmentedControl doesn't have the 'sliderEventIB' method.

The 'addTarget' section of the method asks: "who do I inform once an event occurs?".  In this case, you specified that the UISegmentedControl should be informed and it should call sliderEventIB on that object.  Instead, you should say

`[seg addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderEventIB) forControlEvents: UIControlEventAllEvents]`